# How to change the content of an element with childNodes (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, child-nodes

How can I change the content of an element with childNodes (Javascript)?
I tried something but it did not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Zitat</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var htmlNode = document.documentElement;
            var emNode = htmlNode.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1];
            emNode.innerHtml = "BBB";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Hello World</li>
            <li>AAA <em>DDD</em> CCC.</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is necessary traversing the DOM in the way of your example?, you could use clases or ids for fastest traversing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Zitat</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
                var arrAllListTags = document.querySelectorAll("li");
                arrAllListTags[1].childNodes[1].textContent = "BBB";
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Hello World</li>
            <li>AAA <em>DDD</em> CCC.</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Script can be simplified to `document.querySelector("li em").textContent = "BBB";` (along with the listener)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the script tag should be placed AFTER the markup, otherwise it will be run before the actual html you are trying to modify is actually rendered. Second of all, I think your selectors are wrong. `childNodes` is a valid property of DOM objects, but you have a mistake in your chain. Thirdly, I would use `document.querySelector` to target elements, not a chain of `childNodes`. Finally, use `innerHTML` (not innerHtml) to set html content, or `textContent` if it is a Text node you are trying to update.

[MDN Docs on innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: thanks for answering. but its not working. I have to use the childNodes

Comment: +1 The accepted answer takes into account all 3 of these things (using a listener instead of moving the script) however this answer was first and has an explanation. And yes OP's chain was wrong: should be 2, 7, 3, 1. Cryptic? That's why you shouldn't hard code childNodes indexes even once.